# Harmonic fitting by using curve-fit

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem fitting data by an harmonic function :

```
Harmonic = a0 + a1*np.cos(2*np.pi*(x- b1) /tho1) + a2*np.cos(2*np.pi*(x- b2) /tho2) + a3*np.cos(2*np.pi*(x- b3) /tho3)
```

where a0 is a thermal average, a1, a2, a3 are the amplitudes, b1, b2, b3 are the phases, and tho1=8, tho2=12, tho3=24 are the periods of each oscillation.

the data is :

```
Temperature_2 =  [1054.36258, 1092.96819, 1051.45602, 1058.94926, 1083.66115, 1080.66721
, 1046.96163, 1018.42441, 1049.44307, 1068.91551, 1018.44764, 1035.11906
, 1020.44599,  993.275818 1037.41013, 1005.4047,  1025.73646,  975.301913
, 1000.45743, 1033.21562, 1037.31104,  968.730834, 907.474634, 930.465587
, 998.967526, 911.791887, 915.951873, 742.723487, 709.890191, 760.674339
, 751.491228, 723.875166, 741.451471, 749.69441,  743.337883, 700.286359
, 720.250078, 732.189596, 693.097572, 782.342462, 711.995854, 684.432159
, 761.195087, 746.725427, 744.614939, 648.985204, 676.023106, 689.141056
, 627.855922, 707.298358, 652.207871, 652.609278, 680.52524,  689.328581
, 678.148423, 728.229663, 691.857497, 743.998987, 696.885527, 733.249599
, 722.833678, 734.832942, 719.049095, 703.573908, 711.15146,  689.345427]
```

and :

```
time_2 = [datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 14, 24),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 19, 12),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 23, 9),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 26, 38),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 29, 55),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 32, 52),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 35, 36),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 38, 26),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 41, 13),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 44, 16),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 47, 12),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 50, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 53, 2),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 56, 17),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 18, 59, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 3, 14),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 6, 28),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 10, 4),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 13, 46),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 17, 47),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 21, 35),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 25, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 29, 22),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 33, 41),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 38, 38),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 43, 16),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 19, 47, 53),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 1, 57, 23),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 2, 4, 3),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 2, 10, 46),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 2, 18, 6),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 2, 25, 14),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 2, 32, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 2, 39, 35),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 2, 46, 49),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 2, 54, 43),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 3, 2, 33),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 3, 10, 15),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 3, 17, 28),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 3, 24, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 3, 32, 8),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 3, 39, 13),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 3, 46, 10),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 3, 52, 48),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 3, 59, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 4, 5, 39),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 4, 11, 59),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 4, 18, 27),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 4, 24, 49),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 4, 31, 7),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 4, 39, 18),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 4, 46, 26),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 4, 53, 13),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 5, 0, 11),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 5, 8, 57),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 5, 15, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 5, 22, 6),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 5, 28, 5),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 5, 34, 57),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 5, 40, 4),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 5, 44, 45),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 5, 49, 8),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 5, 54, 41),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 5, 58, 46),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 6, 2, 35),
 datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 8, 6, 6, 18)]
```

and this is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

plt.figure(7)
plt.plot(time_2, Temperature_2, 'g:')
tho1 = 8; tho2 = 12;  tho3 = 24
def Harmonic(x, a0, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3):
    return a0 + a1*np.cos(2*np.pi*(x- b1) /tho1) + a2*np.cos(2*np.pi*(x- b2) /tho2) + a3*np.cos(2*np.pi*(x- b3) /tho3)
ts = np.array([t.timestamp() for t in time_2])
parameters, covariance = curve_fit(Harmonic, ts, Temperature_2, p0=(np.mean(Temperature_2), 1100, 1100, 1100, np.mean(ts), np.mean(ts), np.mean(ts)))
plt.plot(time_2, Harmonic(ts, *parameters), 'r')
plt.show()
```

and this is my result :

[image]

I tried a lot guess but the fit is always bad, and it give me an error message :

```
/home/lhoussine/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:828: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated',
```

The question is how to improve the quality of this fit ?

@Mad Physicist @bnaecker  Can you help please

Comment: Automatic Curve fitting is more of art than exact science. from looking at your data, there is clear dropping slope. Either split your fitting into two batches or apply corrective factor eliminating the dropping slope.

Comment: @pinegulf Can you explain the method please